# Ruby on Rails - has_many relationship with condition that needs a join

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations

I'm working in RoR 3..2.11. I have 4 classes: Person, Agreement, Relationship, and Role. My situation is as follows:

This is in Person:

```
has_many :relationships
has_many :agreements, {
  through: :relationships
}
has_many :current_agreements, {
  source: :agreements,
  through: :relationships,
  conditions: "agreements.start_date <= NOW() AND agreements.end_date >= NOW()"
}
```

This is in Relationship:

```
belongs_to Role
```

A new role has been added to the database ("Past"), so that live agreements can be assigned to another person. Sot the previous person on the agreement still has a relationship to the agreement, but should no longer have it come up under current_agreements. So I need to take into account relationships.role.name. Something like this:

```
has_many :current_agreements, {
  source: :agreements,
  through: :relationships,
  conditions: "agreements.start_date <= NOW() AND agreements.end_date >= NOW() AND role.name != 'Past'"
}
```

The issue here is pretty clear cut, role is not in the query so role.name fails. Is there a way to join the role table by the relationships.id for the association?

I've thought of redefining current_agreements as a method instead, but the project needs it to be an association in certain places so I'd really rather just redefine the association instead of re-factoring the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think that current_agreements **shouldn't** be an association. Does it make sense to ever say

```
@person.current_agreements << @agreement
```

?  If so, would this set start date and end date, and the associated role?

You say you don't want to refactor it but you could spend more time trying to bash a square peg into a round hole by keeping it as an association.

What about a named scope on Agreement like

```
#in Agreement
scope :current, includes(:role).where("agreements.start_date <= NOW() AND agreements.end_date >= NOW() AND role.name != 'Past'")
```

Then you can say

```
@person.agreements.current
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that Max Williams is right. This should not be a relation, and I like the Max's approach.

But something that sounds complicated, it's that you don't want to refactor. Remember that one important thing when you design software is to be prepared for the change. If it's difficult to refactor, maybe you should take a look to your tests, or the way that your classes are coupled.

Take a look to the Max's approach, it's simple and clear. And with Ruby/Rails (and of course with tests) the refactor could be enjoyable, to get your desirable behavior.

I like this [book](http://www.poodr.com/). It could explain better than me, my previous words.